# Erro na definição de propriedade JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou utilizando a API [SCEditor](https://www.sceditor.com/) e quando carrego a página, aparece o seguinte erro:

0x800a138f - Erro em tempo de execução do JavaScript: Não é possível definir a propriedade '_sceditor' de referência indefinida ou nula

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="minified/themes/default.min.css" />
<script src="minified/sceditor.min.js"></script>
<script src="minified/formats/bbcode.js"></script>
<script src="minified/formats/xhtml.js"></script>
<script>
 var textarea = document.getElementById('example');
 sceditor.create(textarea, {
 format: 'xhtml',
 style: 'minified/themes/content/default.min.css'
});
</script>
```

Comment: Pode ser que seu script esteja executando antes de carregar os scripts do plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DOMContentLoaded`, para checar quando o documento estiver carregado, assim:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var textarea = document.getElementById('example');
    sceditor.create(textarea, {
        format: 'xhtml',
        style: 'minified/themes/content/default.min.css'
    });
});
```